# My colocasia esculenta is turning yellow

Tags: houseplants

As i said in the title, one of the leaves of my colocausia is turning almost completely yellow at this point. I wish to know if the plant lacks something, or if there is anything im doing wrong within its cares.

I have it inside my apartment at full shade, next to the window so it gets some indirect light. I water the soil every two days, and If is helps at all I had it in a glass of water for two months so it grew roots and last month I put it in a pot. The pot is well drained.

If you have any idea of what it might be I'll appreciate if you let me know. Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it an older leaf? Plants loose old leaves all the time.  That should be expected.

I'm not sure where you are located, but indoors full shade is equal to dense shade outdoors.   Your plant can get some direct light indoors.  This plant would benefit from morning sun.  Outdoors in hot climates it should be in light shade, but not dense.  If you are living in far north location, like northern Europe or Canada, your plant would benefit from some direct afternoon sun.  I think at minimum you should give your plant more light.

Water.  This plant likes to be very moist in a pot, but not wet.  It can tolerate wet outdoors, but in a pot it is best to only keep it moist not wet. Don't water on a schedule.  Put your finger in the pot at a depth of 5cm or 2".  If you can feel wet soil it is too wet to water.  You want to keep it consistently moist.

Comment: I live in South America, and weather here is humid sub tropical. Currently summer in here, and the temperatures are considerably high. I'll put it outwards so it gets some sun in the morning and check the moist like you said, thanks for your advice.